# Where is Gottingen?

Tags: discussion, tags

I have never heard of Gottingen.  I have heard of Göttingen, however.  Those who lack an *umlaut*-endowed keyboard usually resort to `ö ⟶ oe`. Thus, [gottingen](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gottingen) ⟶ [goettingen](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/goettingen).

Comment: There seem to be no good uses for city-connected tags anyway? Neither Athens, nor Copenhagen nor anything else I found, except for a stretchy 'ancient-rome'. 'Gottingen' doesn't exist, indeed, except for 4 Qs here, where its use is questionable anyway. So, while this metaQ appears to request a change in the spelling of an existing tag, the proper solution seems to be burn the entire tag?

Comment: @LаngLаngС A country tag may be enough. However, I did not create the tag and it's not for me to decide to burn it.

Comment: Nor did I say that you did… I'd actually agree with you: *if* there is a tag for Göttingen, it must not be spelled 'gotingen'. However, I didn't +1 this, yet, as I do not see the real scope of it. In any case my view of it is that tha tag creator made a mistake, twice. Creating it in the first place, and spelling it incorrectly on top. Then *we* made another mistake and letting that situation stand. My proposed solution would be to just burn it. Either way, if you'd explain the details of the problem here in the q, it'd be UV-worthy, regardless of how/which solution is then agreed upon in As.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that much confusion arises from [gottingen](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gottingen) not being 100% the correct spelling of Göttingen (especially since there is no Gottingen), so I think it's no problem to leave things as they are.

Comment: Hm. EngWP uses 'ö' as well. And SE search seems rather unfuzzy. — Why, however is there even that tag? People searching for that? Are there other tags like that? What if they would like to search for example Copenhagen, Copenhague, Kopenhagen, K(j)øbenhavn?